# When does integrating the characteristic function give us the length of an open set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I just saw the following proof:
If $G_{1}, G_{2}\subset [a, b]$ are two open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, each of which is the union of a finite number of disjoint open intervals, then we have:$$l(G_{1} \cup G_{2}) + l(G_{1} \cap G_{2}) = l(G_{1}) + l(G_{2})$$
Here, $l(G)$ where $G$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ refers to the sum of the lengths of the disjoint open intervals that $G$ forms a union of. Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ may be written uniquely as the disjoint union of countably many open intervals.

$Proof$: $G_{1} \cup G_{2}$ and $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$ are also open sets on $[a, b]$, each the union of a finite number of disjoint open intervals. It follows that the characteristic functions of $G_{1}, G_{2}, G_{1} \cup G_{2}$ and $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$ are step functions on $[a, b]$, and are thus Riemann integrable on this interval.

Moreover, we have $$\chi_{G_{1} \cup G_{2}}(x) + \chi_{G_{1} \cap G_{2}}(x) = \chi_{G_{1}}(x) + \chi_{G_{2}}(x)   \space\space \forall x \in [a, b]$$

Integrating, $$\int_a^b\chi_{G_{1} \cup G_{2}}(x) + \int_a^b\chi_{G_{1} \cap G_{2}}(x) = \int_a^b\chi_{G_{1}}(x) + \int_a^b\chi_{G_{2}}(x) $$
As each open set is the union of a finite number of disjoint open intervals, the value of this integral gives us the length of each open set. Therefore, the result holds. $\blacksquare$

I was wondering if this could be extended to prove the same result for arbitrary open sets contained in $[a, b]$ in a completely analogous way. The possible issues I see with this are:

1. Is the characteristic function of an arbitrary bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}$ Riemann integrable? My hunch is that it should be- such an open set is the union of countably many disjoint open intervals. I believe that the characteristic function is discontinuous only at the endpoints of these intervals. Does this mean that it could have at most a countable number of discontinuities? This would make it Riemann integrable.
2. Secondly, if it *is* Riemann integrable, does the value of the integral still give us the length of the open set? Again, from the definition, I believe that this should be the case.

Also, I wanted to know which kind of sets on $\mathbb{R}$ a similar approach works with. I haven't really studied measure, and I don't know where to look for answers, but would be happy for any pointers.

Comment: The answers to your questions 1 and 2 are yes and yes.
Well, that really does depend on how you define 'similar' and 'length'.
At this point, however, you are basically encoaching on introduction to measure theory, so you'd be best off reading some text on it.

Comment: The characteristic function of an open set need not be Riemann integrable. For example if $U$ is the complement of a *fat* Cantor set, its characteristic function is not Riemann integrable. It all works without problems if you use the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: What would be a good introduction to measure theory to start with?

Comment: @DanielFischer What does *fat*  mean? But yes, I guess it makes sense that it wouldn't be Riemann integrable- it would be discontinuous at uncountably many points. I'm finding it hard to reconcile the fact that an open set is the disjoint union of countably many open intervals and that its characteristic function could have uncountably many discontinuities. Does this have something to do with order types? I could be very off, though.

Comment: A fat Cantor set is a Cantor set with positive (Lebesgue) measure. If you take the ordinary middle-thirds Cantor set, the characteristic function of the complement is Riemann integrable, since its set of discontinuities (the Cantor set) has measure $0$. It's still uncountable, though.

Comment: Oh, you're right, my bad. It does have measure zero.